# Why does this code load with a blank space on the right on an iPhone?

Tags: html, css

So in both portrait and landscape the right 30% or so of the screen is just white, only on iPhone and maybe other small screens, as if the width were less than 100%.
Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="loading">
<div id="loading-message">
    <p>Please enable Javascript to view this site.</p>
    <p class="tar">-Thanks</p>
</div>
<div id="loadingBar">
    <div id="loadingBarInner"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

And relevant CSS:

```
#loading {
background: gray;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
height: 1800px;
box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 500px black;
}
#loading-message {
margin: auto;
border-radius: 30px;
padding: 100px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px 10px black;
width: 300px;
margin-top: 200px;
font-size: 30px;
font-weight: bold;
}
#loadingBar {
margin: auto;
width: 350px;
height: 30px;
margin-top: 300px;
border-radius: 5px;
border: 2px solid black;
padding: 2px;
}
#loadingBarInner {
background: #6d0019; /* Old browsers */
height: 30px;
width: 0px;
border-radius: 5px;
}
```

Comment: you have fixed width of loadingbar and loading-massage divs, your iphone has less width i think and that's why there is blank space on right

Comment: So what do you think the fix would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> instead of using fixed padding in **#loading-message** use padding
>   with percentage also use max-width and min-width properties instead of
>   fixed width in **#loadingBar** and **#loading-message**. your iphone has about 400px width and you defined 100px
>   padding and width of 350px. on big screens it's no problem but in your
>   iphone it will always load with blank space on right side.

```
#loading {
background: gray;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
height: 1800px;
box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 500px black;
}
#loading-message {
margin: 0 auto;
border-radius: 30px;
padding: 10%;
max-width:300px;
min-width:50px;
box-shadow: 0px 0px 50px 10px black;
margin-top: 200px;
font-size: 30px;
font-weight: bold;
}
#loadingBar {
margin: auto;
max-width:300px;
min-width:50px;
height: 30px;
margin-top: 300px;
border-radius: 5px;
border: 2px solid black;
}
#loadingBarInner {
background: #6d0019; /* Old browsers */
height: 30px;
width: 0px;
border-radius: 5px;
}​
```

> also u can use media queries...  [media queries](http://cssmediaqueries.com/what-are-css-media-queries.html)

Answer (score -1):

What iPhone do you have?

Try to play with the widths.

Comment: Try to play with the widths.